# NullpointerException onPostExecute -

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm having a bit of trouble getting Async to work correctly. I have my doInBackground passing a string of a JSON response, which my onPostExecute will parse and then send to the view, but I keep getting a null pointer for my onPostExecute. I **know** that it's getting a proper response back because my Log prints the JSON string I'm expected.

Am I not passing something correctly?

Here's my stacktrace:

```
07-07 13:26:33.757: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5714): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.dsgunter.randompokemongenerator.Generator$LoadPokemon.onPostExecute(Generator.java:153)
    at com.dsgunter.randompokemongenerator.Generator$LoadPokemon.onPostExecute(Generator.java:113)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and my code, which I'll post in a gist for brevity's sake:

https://gist.github.com/verkaufer/88eeb44a0997a4a49779

Comment: Can you place a breakpoint at Generator.java:153 and see what is null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is at `progressDialog.dismiss()`. That `progressDialog` variable is null. You created a `pDialog` local to the onPreExecute method above that, which is what I think you really want to be dismissing.

Answer (score 0):

Your `progressDialog` variable looks to never be initialized, so it is `null`. And this line

```
progressDialog.dismiss();
```

then throws NPE because of that.

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize `progressDialog`, so it is `null`. I guess you want to dismiss the dialog  created in `onPreExecute`, so add this line:

```
progressDialog = pDialog;
```